# How to define the SecondaryTable when it is not One-To-One relationship with the primary table

Tags: java, jpa

IN a project, we have to map one Entity to two tables.
table part_info stores the commodity info, table part_label stores the label that will be shown on screen.

```
Table part_info
id part_no part_description

Table part_label
id part_no_label part_description_label
```

then in our Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="part_info")
@SecondaryTable(name="part_label",pkJoinColumns=    {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id")})
public class PartInfo implements Serializable {
    @id
    private int id;
@Column(name = "part_no")
private String partNo;
@Column(name = "part_description")
private String partDesc;
@Column(table="part_label",name="part_no_label")
private String partNoLabel;
@Column(table="part_label",name="part_description_label")
private String partDescLabel;
    ....
}
```

but this will only map one record of part_info to one record of part_label.

In our case, different part info may use the same part label.
e.g. 
we will use label retrieved from part_label as below:

```
Part# 
Part Desc
```

but we retrieved many part info from part_info table

```
PA123 AAA
PA123 DDD
PA234 BBB
PA345 CCC
```

Then in UI, we will show as:

```
Part#:PA123  Part Desc:AAA
Part#:PA123  Part Desc:DDD
```

If use above @SecondaryTabel, each part_info and each part_label are One-To-One relationship, if need to retrieve two records of parts PA123, also need to retrieve same label twice.

Is there any way that one part label can map to many part info?

Comment: I don't understand how both tables are linked. Which column is a foreign key to which other column? How do you get the part_label row associated to a given part_info row?

Comment: the annotation
@SecondaryTable(name="part_label",pkJoinColumns=    {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id")})
defines the column 'id' in table part_label will reference the column 'id' in table part_info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand SecondaryTable, since it is only ever for one to one situation, and if the object is deleted then the row from both tables is deleted. There is no "reuse" of entries in the secondary table ... since the secondary table has a FK to the primary table!!!

If you want to reuse some data then make that a separate entity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
It is my first choice to map one Entity to two tables using SecondaryTable. Maybe it is true that cannot reuse entries in secondary table.
but using separate entries cannot fit our UI, in UI we will get label and value from the same Entity. We cannot see how to get label and value from different Entity and set to the same form.
anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think the most logical solution would be to model `PartLabel` as a separate entity and create a `ManyToOne` relationship in `PartInfo` to a `PartLabel`.

Comment: Hi, as describe in above reply to DataNucleus, different Entity cannot map our UI.
I think we will consider storing same entries in both part_label and part_info. though duplicate entries in part_label will waste some disk space.